# How to achieve a valid null-option with select ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

There are a couple of questions and answers around this topic here, but I cannot find a solution which is working the way it should be for my case.

Just imagine I have an object like this

```
$scope.person = {name: 'Peter', category1: null, category2: null};
```

In a different variable I receive a list of categories via a `$resource` call with a result like this:

```
$scope.categories = [{id:1, name:'Supplier'}, {id:2, name:'Customer'}];
```

Now it's easy to build a select with `ng-options` to choose from `categories` to set the selected `category.id` as `person.category1` or `person.category2`.

But how can I do that when `category1` is mandatory while `category2` can still be a valid *null* value?

So basically what I am looking for now are two selects with the following options:

```
//Select1
- Select Category1 (disabled)
- Customer (value: 1)
- Supplier (value: 2)

//Select2
- Select Category2 (disabled)
- No Category (value: null)
- Customer (value: 1)
- Supplier (value: 2)
```

### EDIT

I added a [**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/F3R3ajt4Uwxawq0JVIaC?p=preview) based on [*@Mistalis answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42342420/4927984), which shows what I want to achieve: Each select should have a disabled placeholder option and one should support a "valid null option".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `option` *(null)* to your `select` with the following:

```
<select ng-model="categ.selected" ng-options="c.name for c in categories">
    <option value="">No category</option>
</select>
```

### [Demo on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o2oHiHX0jhPXWQRV2GMm?p=preview)

---

`categ.selected` can be default set to null in your controller if needed:

```
$scope.categ = {"selected": null};
```

---

### Update from comment:

It seems you can't hard-code 2 options in a ng-options, so I suggest you to push the "No category" option in `categories` in your controller:

```
$scope.categories.push({id:null, name:'No category', noCat:'true'});
```

*Note the `noCat: 'true'` that will be used to be not displayed on the first `select`.*

Now your HTML becomes:

```
<select ng-model="person.category1" 
        ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in categories | filter: {noCat: '!true'}">
    <option value="" disabled>Select Category 1</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="person.category2" ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in categories">
    <option value="" disabled>Select Category 2</option>
</select>
```

### [New Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sLy4NzoQdqFxklNNYpdm?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I knew that as well as the other question's input. I took your plunkr, thanks a lot and extended it to hopefully show what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding - it didn't solve my issue. Could you kindly check my edited question with the plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to validate form with angular's form controller, you can't use empty value, it won't be considered as valid. You have to use `(int)0` instead.

```
  <select ng-model="person.category1" ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories | filter: {id: '!' + 0}" required>
    <option value="">Select Category 1</option>
  </select>
  <select placeholder="Select Category 2" ng-model="person.category2" ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories" required>
    <option value="">Select Category 2</option>
  </select>
```

If you want to make *Select Category* options to be unavailable to select at all (like a placholder), then add `disabled` attribute to `<option>`

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thesameson/dc0db2ku/) with your example.